# Django relation does not exist when running test

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-postgresql

I'm using Django `2.2.3` and Postgres.

I'm trying to add tests into the project and constantly running into an error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist` at test db creation step, when doing either `python ./manage.py test` or `python ./manage.py test app_name`.

First of all, *my suggestion* is that I've messed my db schema a little - some time ago development team was asked to import several tables from another db and I've done it via direct importing using pgsql. Than I created models using `python manage.py inspectdb` and placed them into a separate app.
That command created an initial migration, which looks like that:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = []

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='SomeModelName',
        fields=[
            (
                'id',
                models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            ),
            ('some_other_field)', models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)),
        ],
        options={'db_table': 'some_existing_table_name', 'managed': False,},
    ),
```

Everything works fine, since than I've created and applied several migrations without any issues. But now I've got stuck with that tests issue.

After a brief investigation I found, that `inspectdb` also created models for some auth tables, and they are present in models.py of that apps with old tables. So, the following lines are present into initial migration of the discussed app:

```
        migrations.CreateModel(
        name='AuthGroup',
        fields=[
            (
                'id',
                models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            ),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)),
        ],
        options={'db_table': 'auth_group', 'managed': False,},
    ),
```

and in models.py:

```
class AuthGroup(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'auth_group'
```

I think, that this may be related to an issue, but I've tried to removing that app from `INSTALLED_APPS`, deleting that app at all, but nothing worked. I still get those errors while running tests

Any ideas, what can I do to fix this issue?
Maybe, this behavior is caused by something else?

**P.S.** this issue is unrelated to problems with South package, because it's not used in this project.

Thanks.

**P.P.S.** `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
[
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
+ PROJECT_APPS
+ THIRD_PARTY_APPS
)
```

Comment: You might have messed up with your old migration files, drop the db and try again

Comment: As those migrations are already applied in prod, you can remove the chunks related to `AuthGroup` from migration file(s), drop that app from `INSTALLED_APPS` and then tell your test suite to recreate the test DB.

Comment: @heemayl It didn't work ;( The error is still present after removing that app from INSTALLED_APPS and removing those chunks from migration (and applying new version of the migration)

Comment: @AlexShein Did you recreate the test DB? Also, can you add the full trackback?

Comment: @heemayl Yep, I did recreate it. It fails executing sql `ALTER TABLE "auth_user_groups" ADD CONSTRAINT "auth_user_groups_group_id_97559544_fk_auth_group_id" FOREIGN KEY ("group_id") REFERENCES "auth_group" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. Traceback link: https://gist.github.com/AlexShein/e2224bbdffb2f18b4e0ff2f9cf052961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was somehow related to custom user model, which was declared the following way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

It turned out that replacing it with default Django User fixed the issue.